# How to anchor the origin (0,0,0) to the center of multiple generated images in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I have the following file to generate an animation with a separate file

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\foreach \vari in {0,5,10,15,...,360}
{

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      scale=.5,
      x={(-1cm,-.25cm)},y={(1cm,-.25cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},
      rotate around z=\vari
    ]

        % coordinates

        \coordinate (A) at (3,-3,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (3,3,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (-3,3,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (-3,-3,0);
        \coordinate (E) at (3,-3,3);
        \coordinate (F) at (3,3,3);
        \coordinate (G) at (-3,3,3);
        \coordinate (H) at (-3,-3,3);

        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](C,D,H,G)

        % Axes 3d

        \draw[->,>=stealth] (3,0,0) -- (5,0,0);
        \draw[->,>=stealth] (0,3,0) -- (0,5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);

        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](B,C,G,F)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,D,H,E)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,B,F,E)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](G,H,E,F)

        \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](A,B B,C C,G G,H H,E E,F E,A F,B F,G)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](E,F,G,H)
        \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,C,D)

        \draw[->,>=stealth] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,7); 
    \end{tikzpicture}  
}
\end{document}
```

but my problem is that the point (0,0,0) changes place during rotation and I would like to have it in a single place throughout the entire animation. Is there a way to anchor it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the point `(0,0,0)` that changes but the bounding box. To prevent this from happening, you can set a bounding box yourself, e.g. by saying

```
  \path[use as bounding box] (-4,-1.45) rectangle (4,4);
```

This yields

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\foreach \vari in {0,5,10,15,...,360}
{

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (-4,-1.45) rectangle (4,4);
  \begin{scope}
    [
      scale=.5,
      x={(-1cm,-.25cm)},y={(1cm,-.25cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},
      rotate around z=\vari
    ]

        % coordinates
        \coordinate (A) at (3,-3,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (3,3,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (-3,3,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (-3,-3,0);
        \coordinate (E) at (3,-3,3);
        \coordinate (F) at (3,3,3);
        \coordinate (G) at (-3,3,3);
        \coordinate (H) at (-3,-3,3);

        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](C,D,H,G)

        % Axes 3d

        \draw[->,>=stealth] (3,0,0) -- (5,0,0);
        \draw[->,>=stealth] (0,3,0) -- (0,5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);

        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](B,C,G,F)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,D,H,E)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](A,B,F,E)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt](G,H,E,F)

        \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](A,B B,C C,G G,H H,E E,F E,A F,B F,G)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](E,F,G,H)
        \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,C,D)

        \draw[->,>=stealth] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,7); 
    \end{scope} 
    \end{tikzpicture}  
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would recommend `tikz-3dplot` for that. It allows you to do orthographic projections, and makes it more easy to distinguish hidden from foreground faces. I also use [a routine to determine the minimal bounding box that fits all frames. It also comes with some style for the hidden surfaces, and I added some annotations to the code that may help to understand more easily where to modify it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{plane/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
#1 -- ++ #2 -- ++ #3 -- ++ ($-1*#2$) -- cycle}},
xy plane/.style={plane={#1}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length},0,0)}{(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length},0)}},
xz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length},0,0)}{(0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length})}},
yz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length},0)}{(0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length})}},
get projections/.style={insert path={%
let \p1=(1,0,0),\p2=(0,1,0)  in 
[/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yproj}{sign(\x2)}\xdef\yproj{\yproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}\xdef\zproj{\zproj}}]}},
pics/3d block/.style={code={
\tikzset{3d block/.cd,#1}
\path[get projections];
% start drawing the "hidden surfaces"
\ifnum\zproj=-1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/xy face,xy plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/xy face,xy plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\yproj=1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/yz face,yz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/yz face,yz plane={
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\xproj=1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/xz face,xz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/hidden face,3d block/xz face,xz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
% end drawing the "hidden surfaces"
% start drawing the "forefronts"
\ifnum\yproj=1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/yz face,yz plane={
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/yz face,yz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\xproj=1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/xz face,xz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/xz face,xz plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\zproj>-1
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/xy face,xy plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d block/every face,3d block/xy face,xy plane={
 (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/x length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/y length}/2,
  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d block/z length}/2)}]; 
\fi
}},
3d block/.cd,
xy face/.style={fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt},
xz face/.style={fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt},
yz face/.style={fill=blue!20,opacity=.5,rounded corners=.1pt},
every face/.style={draw,very thick},
hidden face/.style={dashed,thick},
x length/.initial=1,
y length/.initial=1,
z length/.initial=1,
/tikz/retrieve bounding box/.style={insert path={
    let \p1=(current bounding box.south west),
    \p2=(current bounding box.north east)
    in \pgfextra{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{min(\x1,\xmin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{max(\x2,\xmax)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{min(\y1,\ymin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{max(\y2,\ymax)}
    \xdef\xmin{\xmin pt}
    \xdef\xmax{\xmax pt}    
    \xdef\ymin{\ymin pt}
    \xdef\ymax{\ymax pt}  
    %\typeout{\xmin,\xmax,\ymin,\ymax}  
    }}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{0}
\begin{document}
\foreach \vari in {0,5,10,15,...,360}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{-\vari} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,tdplot_main_coords,>=stealth]
 \ifdefined\figbb\relax
    \path \figbb;
    \fi
 \coordinate (A) at (3,-3,-1.0);
 \coordinate (B) at (3,3,-1.0);
 \coordinate (C) at (-3,3,-1.0);
 \coordinate (D) at (-3,-3,-1.0);
 \coordinate (E) at (3,-3,1.0);
 \coordinate (F) at (3,3,1.0);
 \coordinate (G) at (-3,3,1.0);
 \coordinate (H) at (-3,-3,1.0);    
 \foreach \X in {A,B,C,D}
 {\path (\X) node[below]{\X};}
 \draw[dashed] (3,0,-1.0) -- (0,0,-1.0) -- (0,3,-1.0)
 (0,0,-1.0) -- (0,0,1.0);
 \draw[thick,->] (3,0,-1.0) -- (5,0,-1.0);
 \draw[thick,->] (0,3,-1.0) -- (0,5,-1.0);
 \pic{3d block={x length=6,y length=6,z length=2}};
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,1.0) -- (0,0,4);
 \foreach \X in {E,F,G,H}
 {\path (\X) node[above]{\X};}
 \path[retrieve bounding box];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatletter               
\edef\figbb{(\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax)}
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figbb{\figbb}\relax}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean load `tikz-3dplot` instead of `tikz` package? Is there a possible significant reduction in code complexity? I haven't looked into `tikz-3dplot` package so I don't know the commands available in it.

Comment: @Concept7 The `tikz-3dplot` package loads `tikz` and allows you to set the view angles and then does an orthographic projection. That is, it will replace ` x={(-1cm,-.25cm)},y={(1cm,-.25cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},` by something entirely fixed by the view angles.

Comment: @Concept7 I added a `tikz-3dplot` version. True, one needs more preparations, but  you can adjust the view more easily and can also more easily distinguish between foreground and background faces.

Comment: Thanks! I have to study your example but all I can say right now is that it looks impressive!!